# Is strangeness == illusion

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

We find illusions strange. Are the two terms related, if yes, in what sense, I mean more deeply?

Comment: Can you explain further? I consider the creatures in the following picture to be strange but they aren't necessarily illusions.  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4YnDI25yw0M/maxresdefault.jpg.  Also, if I think I see an oasis in the desert, it may be real or it may be an illusion but it isn't necessarily strange - it could appear to be an ordinary oasis.  What sort of connection do you mean?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica  I mean like mental illness ADHD, Alzheimer's, schizophrenia, etc.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica your reply somehow relates to children but does not necessarily correlates to the adult behaviour, or the society in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two words have different meanings.

It is quite normal to see a mirage in the desert (it is not strange) but it is an illusion.

On the other hand, it is strange that the government has shut all schools due to disease, but it is very real.

Their origins are different too.  Illusion is comes from Latin "en-ludare" suggesting "mock, or play at".  Strange comes from French meaning "foreign" and ultimately from Latin "extraneus"  (extra- means  outside)

There is no deep or shallow  connection